# how to avoid inserting duplicate records in table type sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have this query for insert list of data in table 
and now i want avoid insert duplicate records
how i can do it in my code?

please help me

```
-- Create a table type to match your input parameters
CREATE TYPE IdNameTable AS TABLE 
( ID INT, Name NVARCHAR(50) );
GO

-- change your stored procedure to accept such a table type parameter
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Register]
    @Values IdNameTable READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO dbo.Group (Id, Name) 
          -- get the values from the table type parameter
          SELECT 
             Id, Name
          FROM
             @Values

        SELECT 0
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT -1
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Comment: Use `DISTINCT' in your query...

Comment: add an unique index on the field you like to keep unique

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Group (Id, Name) 
SELECT 
  Id, Name
FROM
  @Values
WHERE 
  ID NOT IN (select ID from Group)
```

with full code:

```
-- Create a table type to match your input parameters
CREATE TYPE IdNameTable AS TABLE 
( ID INT, Name NVARCHAR(50) );
GO

-- change your stored procedure to accept such a table type parameter
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Register]
    @Values IdNameTable READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY

        INSERT INTO dbo.Group (Id, Name) 
        SELECT 
           Id, Name
        FROM
           @Values
        WHERE 
           ID NOT IN (select ID from Group)

        SELECT 0
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT -1
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Comment: @user3807529 I'm glad I could help you, don't forget you can also vote for the answers.

Comment: Don't count on every piece of code having this check! Add a unique constraint!

Answer (score 1):

I have used a NOT EXISTS to check to see if ID is available in dbo.Group table and insert only when no match is found. The assumption is that ID is Unique. Please modify the filter inside the Not EXISTS to tiler for your need. Hope it helps

```
CREATE TYPE IdNameTable AS TABLE 
(ID INT, NAME NVARCHAR(50));
GO

-- change your stored procedure to accept such a table type parameter
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Register]
    @Values IdNameTable READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO dbo.Group (Id,NAME)
        -- get the values from the table type parameter
        SELECT   v.Id,
                 v.NAME
        FROM     @Values v
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Group gp WHERE gp.id=v.id)

        SELECT   0
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT   -1
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to add **Unique** constraint to the filed while creating the table for example
create table tble_Name
(
ID int identity (1,1), 
Name nvarchar (50) **Unique** Null 
) 
When you enter a record the query shall prevent duplicate records

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TYPE IdNameTable AS TABLE 
(ID INT, NAME NVARCHAR(50));
GO

-- change your stored procedure to accept such a table type parameter
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Register]
    @Values IdNameTable READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO dbo.Group (Id,NAME)
        -- get the values from the table type parameter
        SELECT   v.Id,
                 v.NAME
        FROM     @Values v
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Group gp WHERE gp.id=v.id)

        SELECT   0
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT   -1
    END CATCH
END
GO
```